# Haystack search in FileFIeld

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using haystack + elasticsearch in my Django project for the following model:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    body = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='notes/')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

How should I change a haystack search index so it could search in `attachment` `FileField`?

```
class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
    body = indexes.CharField(model_attr='body')
    attachment = indexes.CharField(model_attr='attachment')

    def get_model(self):
        return Note

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(timestamp__lte=timezone.now())
```

Comment: Would you like to search in the contents of the attachment or the name of the file?

Comment: @EWit, in the contents (files like PDF/Word/Excel)

Comment: No idea in that case, maybe look at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-haystack/XV-cisEzKRs ?